how to present a specific brain region on right and left side of the brain glass?
I have this mat file from Craddock atlas and all coordinates of every regions are in this file.
mat = scipy.io.loadmat("C:/Users/Monir/Downloads/atlases/craddock.mat")
coordinates = [mat['ROI'][0][i][2].T for i in range(len(mat['ROI'][0]))]
in the picture the first region in AAL atlas are presenting in red.And I used BrainViewer in Matlap.
However, for Craddock atlas I couldn't find any nifti file. So I think using the coordinates I should creat a nifti file from Craddock in MNI152.
please let me know if anyone know how I can craet nifti file or using the coordinates I can present a specific region in brain glass.
